# Avoid using if/else conditions and return early

Tags: php

So I have the following method:

```php
public function get_office_map_url(object $office): string
{
    if ($office === null) {
        return '';
    }
    if (get_field('map_url', $office)) {
        $map_url = get_field('map_url', $office);
    } else {
        $map_fields = [
            get_field('brand', $office),
            get_field('location', $office),
            get_field('address_line_1', $office),
            get_field('address_line_2', $office),
            get_field('city', $office),
            get_field('state', $office),
            get_field('zip_code', $office),
            get_field('country', $office)
        ];
        $map_fields_filter = array_filter($map_fields);
        $map_url = 'https://google.com/maps/search/' . implode(', ', $map_fields_filter);
    }

    return str_replace(' ', '+', $map_url);
}
```

Here is what I'm attempting to do - I want to avoid using a if/else statement, but I can't figure out how to return early and properly - Could anyone give some inputs? Here is my current attempt:

```php
public function get_office_map_url(object $office): string
{
    $map_url = 'https://google.com/maps/search/';
    if ($office === null) {
        return '';
    }
    if (get_field('map_url', $office)) {
        return str_replace(' ', '+', get_field('map_url', $office));
    }
//  else {
//      $map_fields = [
//          get_field('brand', $office),
//          get_field('location', $office),
//          get_field('address_line_1', $office),
//          get_field('address_line_2', $office),
//          get_field('city', $office),
//          get_field('state', $office),
//          get_field('zip_code', $office),
//          get_field('country', $office)
//      ];
//      $map_fields_filter = array_filter($map_fields);
//      $map_url = 'https://google.com/maps/search/' . implode(', ', $map_fields_filter);
//  }

//  return str_replace(' ', '+', $map_url);
}
```

Comment: What's the exact problem with your code? There's no need for `else` after the `return`

Comment: And, in my opinion, since you have a common task to perform in either case (the replacement), I'd leave it just like it is.

Comment: @NicoHaase - Should I run a return for the $map_fields array?

Comment: What does "run a return from an array" mean?

Comment: The two versions seem to do very different things. The second version never uses any of the fields in `$office`.

Comment: "Should I run a return for the $map_fields array?" - if you need it, do it. You should know best what your code should do, or should not ;)

Comment: Also note that `$office` cannot be `null` because the method signature declares it must be an `object`.

Comment: @miken32, then what would be the alternative to the object, `(empty($office))`?

Comment: No alternative is needed. PHP will throw an error if you supply anything that's not an object. You don't have to check for it manually.

Comment: @Tripp why did you remove the code and left an empty `<pre>` box? That made your question not answerable. That does not make sense at all. What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove your first `return` statement. According to your method signature, `$office` will never be null, but will always be an object.

For the second, one can confirm that it is already a valid URL, and simply return it as is.

For the remaining case, note that replacing spaces with pluses is not sufficient encoding for a URI component; use the correct `urlencode` function.

```php
public function get_office_map_url(object $office): string
{
    $map_url = get_field('map_url', $office);
    if (filter_var($map_url, \FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)) {
        return $map_url;
    }
    $map_fields = [
        get_field('brand', $office),
        get_field('location', $office),
        get_field('address_line_1', $office),
        get_field('address_line_2', $office),
        get_field('city', $office),
        get_field('state', $office),
        get_field('zip_code', $office),
        get_field('country', $office)
    ];
    $map_fields_filter = array_filter($map_fields);
    return 'https://google.com/maps/search/' . urlencode(implode(', ', $map_fields_filter));
}
```

I would also note that whatever kind of object `$office` is, this functionality should be incorporated into a method. Ditto for using this (global?) `get_field` function instead of properties on `$office`. This seems like some very strangely implemented object-oriented programming.

Comment: The urlencode resolved the str_replace issue, much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You can omit the `else` and use `goto`.

`goto` is very useful to reduce nesting on `if`/`else` statement. It can also reduce duplicate code most of the time.

### Additional correction

As miken32 has mentioned, the `$office` cannot be `null` as the type hint requires it be an object. You need to use `?object` to allow the caller to pass `null`.

---

### Code

```php
public function get_office_map_url(?object $office): string
{
    if ($office === null) {
        return '';
    }

    if (get_field('map_url', $office)) {
        $map_url = get_field('map_url', $office);
        goto out;
    }


    $map_fields = [
        get_field('brand', $office),
        get_field('location', $office),
        get_field('address_line_1', $office),
        get_field('address_line_2', $office),
        get_field('city', $office),
        get_field('state', $office),
        get_field('zip_code', $office),
        get_field('country', $office)
    ];
    $map_fields_filter = array_filter($map_fields);
    $map_url = 'https://google.com/maps/search/' . implode(', ', $map_fields_filter);


out:
    return str_replace(' ', '+', $map_url);
}
```

---

### Removing duplicate call

If the call to `get_field` for conditional statement is enough to be done only once (I don't know whether it affects the flow or not as there is no information about that). You can write it only one like this.

```php
public function get_office_map_url(?object $office): string
{
    if ($office === null) {
        return '';
    }


    $map_url = get_field('map_url', $office);
    if ($map_url) {
        goto out;
    }

    $map_fields = [
        get_field('brand', $office),
        get_field('location', $office),
        get_field('address_line_1', $office),
        get_field('address_line_2', $office),
        get_field('city', $office),
        get_field('state', $office),
        get_field('zip_code', $office),
        get_field('country', $office)
    ];
    $map_fields_filter = array_filter($map_fields);
    $map_url = 'https://google.com/maps/search/' . implode(', ', $map_fields_filter);


out:
    return str_replace(' ', '+', $map_url);
}
```

Comment: What is the value of using this rather obscure statement, compared to simply putting a `return` statement in the conditional clause?

Comment: @miken32 you will have duplicate `str_replace` in your code without `goto`.

Comment: Anyway, this `goto` style is often used in C programming. As I always see in the Linux kernel source code. But I rarely see this in PHP codebase.

Comment: Yes you will. I think most would find that bit of repetition preferable to weird language features that require you to go find a label before you know what's happening. Also, I'd bet that `str_replace` call should more properly be a `urlencode` call.

Comment: See also `http_build_query`.

Comment: Yeah, if the intention is to pass the `$map_url` to URL-encoded argument, I completely agree to use `urlencode` (for URL parameter) or `rawurlencode` (for POST request body).

Comment: Please, avoid `goto`. It makes the code look rare.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```
public function get_office_map_url(object $office): string
{
    if ($office === null) {
        return '';
    }
    if (get_field('map_url', $office)) {
        $map_url = get_field('map_url', $office);
        return str_replace(' ', '+', $map_url);
    }
     $map_fields = [
        get_field('brand', $office),
        get_field('location', $office),
        get_field('address_line_1', $office),
        get_field('address_line_2', $office),
        get_field('city', $office),
        get_field('state', $office),
        get_field('zip_code', $office),
        get_field('country', $office)
     ];
     $map_fields_filter = array_filter($map_fields);
     $map_url = 'https://google.com/maps/search/' . implode(', ', $map_fields_filter);
        
     return str_replace(' ', '+', $map_url);
}
```

You always need if statement to evaluate your conditions, however once the condition is accomplished there is no point to keep evaluation other conditions, so inside your brackets do all the magic an just return.

There is a god improvement, put the most probably scenarios on top. Yo may save a few nanoseconds :)

Comment: What is "this"? Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it